# I can login to my Xubuntu X desktop but not virtual terminal

Tags: xubuntu, login, virtual-terminal

I recently bought a Dell computer with Xubuntu installed on it. I was able to change the login and password, and can log in to the X desktop, but when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or any other F keys), the desktop switches to a terminal, but it tells me that my login and password are incorrect. How do I fix this?

Comment: I found the answer to my question at askubuntu.com/questions/266706, in case anyone else needs help with this!